# Data Viewer not triggered in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Using:
Windows 7 Enterprise; Visual Studio Pro 2017 (15.3.5); SSDT 15.1

Can't get Data Viewer to pop up on my SSIS package. I did do some Google-fu, and can't find anything relevant (or newer than 2010).

I've used the DV many times in the past, so I'm aware of how to enable a DV, the magnifying glass icon is present on the data flow paths, and I know it's not an issue of a hidden window since my package never actually pauses at any of the DV-enabled points.

Has anyone experienced this before? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tired deleting and recreating the dataviewer?  Is the dataviewer docked, so you just can't see it?  Is SSDT losing it's mind?  :)

Comment: I do face the similar issue with VS 2017 with SSDT for VS 2017. However, I am still figurig out the solution.

Comment: have you find a solution yet?

Comment: When I change the Target Server property in configuration to SQL Server 2016 (eventhough target is SQL Server 2017) , data viewer works fine

Comment: Same problem here. But so far no solution.

Answer (score 7):

I found this question because I was having this problem also.  For me it turns out that the Data Viewer was not popping up simply because there were no rows in the underlying recordset. I had expected it would pop up anyhow and show zero rows, but apparently not.

Comment: 1+ Gah... this was exactly my issue, I forgot that I had truncated my staging table earlier! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On project property page Change the "TargetServerVersion" so the target server is the same as your database server.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: @Roy Bercovitch, is there any workaround to use DV with target server SQL Server 2017? I am in a position that I used a dependency which will not work with target SQL Server 2016 so just checking around. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Or the closest to it. I was using SQL Server 2008 (!), the package was looking for 2017 and setting it to 2014 still worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the Runtime for debugging to 32Bit (right click your project, choose "Properties"-entry, click "Debugging", set "Run64BitRuntime" to "false")

In my case i was able to use Dataviewers then.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have downstream of the DV? Can it be optimized out? For example, sometimes I will want a DV after a transform and nothing after that (ie, for debugging). Since I can only put a DV on a connecting line, I will stick a dummy transform (say, Union All or Multiplex) so that I can use it's connecting line.

However, sometimes SSDT will optimize that transform -- it'll notice that the Union All's output is going nowhere and deduce that it is not needed, and there goes my viewer. I usually see this outside of the IDE (ie, dtexec), but once in a while inside the IDE.

Also, you could try resetting your IDE's window layout (under the Window menu). Sometimes the viewers hide outside of the desktop, particularly if you're RDPing to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have facing same issue , i have deleted the existing package and create new one.. It is worked for me..!!!